# Create key, value pair for JSON via nest in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I would like to create a key, value pair for a JSON using `d3.nest()`.

The original JSON appears like this:

```
[
{
    "Country": "Mexico", 
    "Climate": 100,
    "Safety Index": 50,
    "Life Expectancy": 80,
    "Corruption": 30,
    "Per Capita Income": 20
},
{
    "Country": "UK",
    "Climate": 70,
    "Safety Index": 80,
    "Life Expectancy": 70,
    "Corruption": 70,
    "Per Capita Income": 80
},
{
    "Country": "US",
    "Climate": 80,
    "Safety Index": 70,
    "Life Expectancy": 90,
    "Corruption": 70,
    "Per Capita Income": 80
}
]
```

I would like to transform it into this:

```
[
{"key": "Mexico", "value":
    [ 
        { "key": "Climate", "value": 100 },
        { "key": "Safety Index", "value": 50 },
        { "key": "Life Expectancy", "value": 80 },
        { "key": "Corruption", "value": 30 },
        { "key": "Per Capita Income", "value": 20 }
    ]},
{"key": "UK", "value":
    [ 
        { "key": "Climate", "value": 70 },
        { "key": "Safety Index", "value": 80 },
        { "key": "Life Expectancy", "value": 70 },
        { "key": "Corruption", "value": 70 },
        { "key": "Per Capita Income", "value": 80 }
    ]},
{"key": "US", "value":
    [ 
        { "key": "Climate", "value": 80 },
        { "key": "Safety Index", "value": 70 },
        { "key": "Life Expectancy", "value": 90 },
        { "key": "Corruption", "value": 70 },
        { "key": "Per Capita Income", "value": 80 }
    ]}
    ]
```

My attempt:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
             .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
             .entries(data);
```

My question is very basic as I'm new to D3. How should I go about changing the structure of the JSON in D3?

**EDIT**

This is to create a separate bar chart per country based on the different categories similar to this example ( http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848 ). If there's a better way I should be thinking about this, let me know.

Comment: Why do you want to transform it? The easiest way to serve data to D3, is to serve it in a table-like format, like your original JSON. Also, the addition of "key" and "value" keys is a bit redundant as this information can easily be extracted from the original format.

Comment: See the edit. For example, d3.keys(data[0]) would bring in "Country" which I need to omit. Could you elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: Why do you need to omit the value for "country"? If you look at the code example you're trying to modify, the code has a value for "country" as well.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I see what you're talking about. That's a way better approach!

Comment: I made some edits to my answer. Let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the exact output that you've provided, and insist on using nests for this, you can use:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
         .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
         .rollup(function(d) {
              var countryGroupedObject = d[0];
              return d3.nest()
                       .key(function(innerKey) { return innerKey; })
                       .rollup(function(innerKey) { return countryGroupedObject[innerKey]; })
                       .entries(Object.keys(countryGroupedObject));
          })
         .entries(data);
```

A potential issue here is that you're assuming that each country will be unique (e.g. there won't be two "Mexico" entries). As such the inner nest only operates on `d[0]` (which will be the first item listed for a given country).

**Edit:** Actually, this won't be *exactly* what you asked for, the country key:value will exist in the inner grouping. If that's a problem, it can be ignored by placing the following before the inner nest:
`delete countryGroupedObject.Country;`

**Edit 2:** The above code uses nested `nest` functions simply because the question asked it that way. In real systems, the inner `nest` makes more sense to me to be pure Javascript, along the lines of:

```
function getGraphParams(countryObj){
    return Object.keys(countryObj)
                   .filter(function(key){ return key !== "Country"; })
                   .map(function(key){ return { key: key, value: countryObj[key] }; })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without D3:

```
var a = ...; // Original Array of JSON
var b = [];
a.forEach(function(item) {
    var r = {};
    r.key = item.Country;
    r.value = [];
    for (var i in item) {
        if (i === "Country") { continue; }
        r.value.push({"key": i, "value": item[i]});
    }
    b.push(r);
});
```

Not sure why you're only using "key" as your key and "value" for you value keys though, that seems to go against the point using implicit keys and values in JSON. But I assume you have reason to be doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> If there's a better way I should be thinking about this, let me know.

If you're going to change your datastructure, why not change it into something like this?

```
[
    ["Mexico", 100, 50, 80, 30, 20],
    ["UK", 70, 80, 70, 70, 80],
    ["US", 80, 70, 90, 70, 80],
]
```

It's a lot smaller and contains no redundancies.

If you want your structure to be as close as possible to the data structure of the code example, I would nevertheless recommend sticking with your original data structure, as the CSV file in the original data structure is converted to a data structure pretty much identical to the data structure of your original JSON file.

Comment: I have some flexibility in how the data is formated. I'll look into both options as I need more pratice! Again, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Zach You might also want to check out the code of http://www.johnslegers.com/map/. While I'm using a GUI that is quite different from what you have in mind, the kind of data being processed is somewhat similar to yours and I'm also using a JSON file as a source.

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to process the JSON data.

Comment: @Zach : Please don't mind the coding style I'm using in that example. The code is quite ugly, which is why I haven't put it on Github yet. Still, it should work perfectly on every modern browser.

Comment: No problem! It's the general idea that counts.

Comment: @Zach : Just saying... I'm kinda pedantic / anal with respect to code being written in an elegant / optimal way, and I would hate it if I would be judged as a programmer based on code that I myself consider ugly code ;-)

Comment: Definitely, I'm the same way